# F# Sliding Window Agent not working with records

Tags: f#, records, agent, observable

I've been sampling an F# snippet written by Tomas Petricek that returns an observable that yields sliding windows of 
containing elements drawn from an input observable. That works just fine when the IObservable passed to the function contains ints or tuples, however if it's an IObservable of records, each resulting array (window) of 'count' elements contains the same value.  And each new window contains the same 'count' elements of the last value observed.  The snippet is reproduced below. Is there something internal to async expressions along with F# records that may be causing this behavior?

```
open System

module Observable =

  /// Returns an observable that yields sliding windows of 
  /// containing elements drawn from the input observable. 
  /// Each window is returned as a fresh array.
  let windowed (count:int) (source:IObservable<_>) =
    { new IObservable<_> with
        member x.Subscribe(observer) =
          // Start an agent that remembers partial windows of length 
          // smaller than the count (new agent for every observer)
          let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun agent ->
            // The parameter 'lists' contains partial lists and their lengths
            let rec loop lists = async { 
              // Receive the next value
              let! value = agent.Receive()

              // Add new empty list and then the new element to all lists.
              // Then split the lists into 'full' that should be sent
              // to the observer and 'partial' which need more elements.
              let full, partial =
                ((0, []) :: lists)
                |> List.map (fun (length, l) -> length + 1, value::l)
                |> List.partition (fun (length, l) -> length = count)

              // Send all full lists to the observer (as arrays)
              for (_, l) in full do
                observer.OnNext(l |> Array.ofSeq |> Array.rev) 
              // Continue looping with incomplete lists
              return! loop partial }

            // Start with an empty list of partial lists
            loop [])

          // Send incoming values to the agent
          source.Subscribe(agent.Post) }
```

Comment: Please include a short reproducable example of your problem inline

Comment: Just a guess, but it might have something to do with the fact that records are reference types while tuples and ints are value types.

Comment: I believe ildjarn meant to say tupes are reference types. (They are reference types.)

Comment: @Curt : Indeed I did! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  Seems like a simpler implementation using System.Reactive rather than the custom implementation of an ObservableSource from the documentation on MSDN for Control.Observable does work as expected.  However, then there may be some issue with that example.